# How do I refresh a gradio button after pressing submit?

Tags: python, user-interface, gradio

I have a simple input/output gradio interface:

```
import gradio as gr

def generate_output(input_text):
    output_text = "Hello, " + input_text + "!"
    return output_text

iface = gr.Interface(fn=generate_output, 
                     inputs= gr.Textbox(label="Input Text"),#gr.Textbox(label="Input Text"), 
                     outputs="text",
                     title="Basic Text Input and Output",
                     description="Enter some text and get a modified version of it as output")

iface.launch(share=False)
```

My objective is using gradio to answer questions in a sequence, like a chatbot.

When I press the submit button, how can I change the label of the input textbox from "input text" to "question 2"?

Answer (score 3):

Such behavior is only possible using the Blocks Layout, as you somehow need to update the input component. Here is an example:

```py
import gradio as gr

counter = 1

def generate_output(input_text):
    global counter
    output_text = "Hello, " + input_text + "!"
    counter += 1
    return output_text, gr.Textbox.update(label=f"Question {counter}")

with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    with gr.Row():
    
        # column for inputs
        with gr.Column():
            input_text = gr.Textbox(label="Input Text")
            submit_button = gr.Button("Submit")
                   
        # column for outputs
        with gr.Column():
            output_text = gr.Textbox()
            
    submit_button.click(
        fn=generate_output,
        inputs=input_text,
        outputs=[output_text, input_text]
    )

demo.launch()
```

Here, the input text component is also passed to `outputs` and then updated in the `generate_output` function using `gr.update`. You could do this too with using gr.Interface, but this would result in the Textbox being displayd also on the output side.

Note, that there also is a [Chatbot Component](https://gradio.app/docs/#chatbot) for Gradio!